# start method only after checking is there a needed value in sharedPref

Tags: java, android, logic

Theres edit text field. It has to work like this:
1) if it is empty - nothing happen
2) if user put some NEW text starts method of TextWatcher with HTTP request which takes JSON object. Also the value of String will put in sharedpreference
3) if user open activity when sharedpreference already have value of previous string it has to just set text from that string and don't start method of TextWatcher with HTTP request. 
So there are three conditions and progrmm has to make request only in case when value of string is not tha same as in shared pref. Now it sends request even if person just open app. I want to avoid wrong requests and make request only after new value of string.

THE MAIN QUESTION: How to launch HTTP request code ONLY in case if value in textfield is not the same as in sharedpref?

P.S. If you think my question is bad. Please tell me in notes NOT JUST MAKE -1 please. Teach new programmers

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        AppCompatButton chooseLanguageButton;
        AppCompatButton cleanButton;
        AppCompatEditText translatedTextOutput;
        AppCompatEditText translatedTextInput;
        String translatedInputString;
        RequestQueue requestQueue;
        final String TAG = "myTag";
        String language;

        SharedPreferences mSettings;
        SharedPreferences textReference;
        SharedPreferences translateReference;
        SharedPreferences longLangReference;
        SharedPreferences shortLangReference;
        final String SAVED_TEXT = "text";
        final String SAVED_TRANSLATION = "translation";
        final String LANGUAGE_LONG = "lang_long";
        final String LANGUAGE_SHORT = "lang_short";
        public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";


        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private Timer timer;

        private TextWatcher searchTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                Log.v(TAG, "in afterTextChanged");
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (translatedTextInput.getText().length() != 0){
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                                    sendJsonRequest();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                         InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                         in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(translatedTextInput.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                    }
                }, 600);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                saveText();
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.v(TAG, "in Oncreate");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            chooseLanguageButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.choose_language_button);
            cleanButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.clean_button);
            translatedTextOutput = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.translated_text_field);
            translatedTextInput = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.translation_input_edit);
            int textLength = translatedTextInput.getText().length();
            translatedTextInput.setSelection(textLength);

            translatedTextInput.addTextChangedListener(searchTextWatcher);

            chooseLanguageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "in chooseLanguageListener");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseLanguageList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            cleanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    translatedTextInput.setText("");
                    translatedTextOutput.setText("");
                }
            });
            mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            if (mSettings.contains(LANGUAGE_LONG)){
                Log.v(TAG, "here");
                chooseLanguageButton.setText(mSettings.getString(LANGUAGE_LONG,""));
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "THERE");
                chooseLanguageButton.setText("Choose language");
            }

            if (mSettings.contains(SAVED_TEXT)){
                Log.v(TAG, "here");
                translatedTextInput.setText(mSettings.getString(SAVED_TEXT,""));
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "boooooom");

            }

            if (mSettings.contains(SAVED_TRANSLATION)){
                Log.v(TAG, "here in TRANSLATION FIELD" + mSettings.getString(SAVED_TRANSLATION,""));
                translatedTextOutput.setText(mSettings.getString(SAVED_TRANSLATION,""));
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "boooooom");
            }

        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        translatedTextInput.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Selection.setSelection(translatedTextInput, );
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();
            mSettings = null;
        }

        void saveText() {
//            mSettings = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_TEXT, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mSettings.edit();
            ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, translatedTextInput.getText().toString());
            ed.putString(SAVED_TRANSLATION, translatedTextOutput.getText().toString());
            ed.apply();
            Log.v(TAG, "Text saved==========>" + translatedTextInput.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        void loadText() {

            textReference = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_TEXT, MODE_PRIVATE);
            translatedTextInput.setText(mSettings.getString(SAVED_TEXT,""));
            translateReference = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_TRANSLATION, MODE_PRIVATE);
            translatedTextOutput.setText(mSettings.getString(SAVED_TRANSLATION,""));
            Log.v(TAG, "IN LOAD TEXT METHOD" + mSettings.getString(SAVED_TEXT,""));
            Log.v(TAG, "IN LOAD TRANSLATION METHOD" + mSettings.getString(SAVED_TRANSLATION,""));
        }


        public void sendJsonRequest() {
            Log.v(TAG, "in sendJsonObject");
            Intent myIntent = getIntent();
//            language = myIntent.getStringExtra("short");
            shortLangReference = getSharedPreferences(LANGUAGE_SHORT, MODE_PRIVATE);
            language = mSettings.getString(LANGUAGE_SHORT,"");
            Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "language short = " + language);
            translatedInputString = translatedTextInput.getText().toString().replace(" ","+");
            String url = String.format(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.request_template),
                    String.format(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.query_Template), translatedInputString, language ));
            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Inside OnResponse" + response.toString());
                    JSONArray results = null;
                    try {
                        results = response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("translations");
                        for (int i=0,j=results.length();i<j;i++) {
                            String webTitle = results.getJSONObject(i).getString("translatedText");
                            translatedTextOutput.setText(webTitle);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error :" + e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "NetworkError");
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!");
                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "AuthFailureError");
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!");
                    } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "NoConnectionError!");
                    } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.");
                    }
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
        }

    }
```

Comment: @ Boris :: I did not down vote this question, but I would think the down vote was because there really doesn't appear to be a question. We would have to read through your code and try to think of all possibilities what could be wrong with your code. Error? Wrong result??

Comment: @Barns52 ok. Thank you for feedback. I just don't know how to make realisation of that logic with that code. MOST problem i don't know how launch HTTP request ONLY if value is new.